# Incorrect string value \xF0\x9F\x98\x8A\xF0\x9F... for column 'desc'

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

I'm having this error and still don't know why.

I predict it's happen because some users try to use an emoji. But I try a lot of emoji and it all work.

I use Mysql 5.7
I already set column to COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci and table to CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Answer (score 0):

There are no 6-bytes code points in utf-8.

```
\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A\xF0\x9F //check this value, its six bytes.
```

[Emoji Unicode Tables](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)

Comment: Thanks. But how to check that value?. I don't know what that is

Comment: @DươngViệtHoàng please see my edit.

Comment: Yes. I can't find any of them have 6-bytes code. I still don't know how some one can insert that value to make that error happened

Comment: It's not a 6-byte UTF-8, but two 4-byte UTF-8 that got truncated.  `\xF0` is the lead byte of a 4-byte sequence.  The first four bytes are UTF-8 for this: .  Assume the ... in the title means there were more bytes and OP didn't provide enough.